# Git - for a single file, number of times each line changed

Tags: git, bash

## Summary

Given a file under Git version control, I want to generate a report using Git built-ins or Bash, which lists how many times each line has changed.

The diffs, hashes, authors and other details are to be discarded, the only outcome required is a number for every line, representing the amount of changes since the beginning of the history.

The file is guaranteed to have the same structure and count of lines, otherwise the report would be to little use.

## Reason

I am training a neural-network, persisting intermediate states to the file system. This export describes the connections and weights for every neuron in the system.

Since the file is under version control, I want to measure the strength of connections by seeing how volatile they are. This volatility could be related to the number of times the connection has been mutated. One connection is one line.

## Problem

I am considering `git log`, `git blame` or a well-fabricated combination of the two to generate such a report.

My actual solution uses `git log` with the `L` flag and iterates line-by-line. While this works, generating the report for a 1000+ LOC file with hundreds of commits is extremely slow.

Please see below snippet to understand where I am at.

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( line=$line_start; line<$line_end; line++ )) ; do
    lines=$(git log -L ${line},${line}:${file_input} | grep -c "diff")
    echo "${line}:${lines}" >> ${file_output}
done
```

## Question

Relying on the VCS - in this case Git - what is an optimal solution regarding execution time to generate a report listing the amount of times each line has changed in a given file?

Comment: This is interesting, but very non-trivial task. The only feasible solution that comes to my mind is to analyze diff's in a backward order, which might be challenging due to not knowing what line was deleted or added in case of a change.

Comment: https://github.com/ptlis/diff-parser

Comment: what about this: `git diff --shortstat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the file is always *k* lines long, and you want to know how many times line *L<sub>i</sub>*, 0 ≤ i < k, has changed—I assume "change from A to B, back to A, back to B" counts as 3 times—the natural solution would seem to be:

```
read file first or last commit
C = [0 for i in num_lines(file)]
L = [file_line[i] for i in num_lines(file)]
for commit in all_remaining_commits_in_forward_or_reverse_order:
    read file from commit
    for i in num_lines(file):
        if file_line[i] != L[i]:
            C[i] += 1
            L[i] = file_line[i]
```

(in pseudo-code).  There's little call for using Git itself for this other than to extract the file from each commit (using, perhaps, `git show <rev>:<path>`) and to get the list of commits (`git log --topo-order <branch>`, perhaps).

Comment: It is safe to assume that the file is always _k_ lines long, and your assumption is correct as well, A→B, B→A, A→B counts as 3.

Comment: I have only had the time to check your git commands and came up with the following: `git log --format=format:%H --topo-order _file_ | xargs -I{} git show {}:_file_`. This generates 25MB output (all stages of the file) in less than a second, so execution time is in fact excellent.

Comment: I guess you mean `--pretty=format:%H` or `--format=%H`. Note that you can use `git rev-list` with essentially the same meaning and arguments as `git log`, though you must supply a starting point (`git log` defaults to `HEAD`), if you always want the full hash ID (`git rev-list` is aimed at shell scripts while `git log` is aimed at user-digestible output).

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I will check how `git rev-list` does and finally implement the pseudo-code. I will accept your answer when I get to the end of that -- though I see nothing that could go wrong.